# 'android.content.res.AssetManager android.content.Context.getAssets()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to read a CSV file outside of main activity but I Keep getting this error can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I keep seeing other people say that you need to have the context for getAssets() but I have context there I'm not sure what to do

```
    package com.xnb569_lab3.Model;


    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.AssetManager;
    import android.util.Log;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Team {
    ArrayList<Avenger> avengers = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;

    public Team(Context context){this.context=context;};
    public void loadAvenger() throws IOException {

        AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
        InputStream inStream = am.open("data.csv");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(inStream);

        while(scan.hasNext()){
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            String cont[] =line.split(",");
            Avenger temp = new Avenger(cont[0],cont[1],cont[2],cont[3],cont[4],cont[5],cont[6],cont[7]);
            avengers.add(temp);
        }


    }
        public Avenger getAvenger(String alias){

    for( Avenger avenger: avengers){
        if(avenger.getAlias().equals(alias))
            return avenger;
    }
    return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you pass the ```Context``` to your CSV reader function? You can edit the question and share your attempted code so that we can help and figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: Sorry about that @Enowneb this is my first post I thought I included an image

Comment: It's ok. Can you also show how you initialize ```Team(Context)``` class and call ```loadAvenger()```?